# Linq/lambda toDictionary() throwing exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, exception, lambda

I have a query that looks something like this

```
return (from item in context.MERCHANDISE_ITEMS
        where item.ORGID == orgId
        select new MerchandiseModel()
        {
            Description = item.DESCRIPTION,
            ...,
            Images = context.MERCHANDISE_IMAGES.Where(i => i.ITEMID == item.ID).ToDictionary(i => i.ID, i => i.IMAGENAME)
        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Images is a Dictionary and MERCHANDISE_IMAGES.ID is int and MERCHANDISE_IMAGES.IMAGENAME is string.

This is throwing System.NotSupportedException, I've tried doing linq (no lambda), same exception.

Here is the exception:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String] ToDictionary[MERCHANDISE_IMAGES,Int32,String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Hylton.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkORM.MERCHANDISE_IMAGES], 
System.Func`2[Hylton.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkORM.MERCHANDISE_IMAGES,
System.Int32], System.Func`2[Hylton.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkORM.MERCHANDISE_IMAGES,System.String])' method,
and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, I've looked through every post on this issue and everything I've seen is doing it the same way. Can anyone point out what I'm missing?

Comment: The error message seems pretty self explanatory.  The query provider can't turn `ToDictionary` into SQL code, so it's throwing an exception.  What SQL would you expect that to be translated into?

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure. I've seen this syntax all over but perhaps in those cases it hasn't been a real SQL query. So there's no way to achieve this I guess?

Comment: Understand what is going on. when you execute "context.MERCHANDISE_IMAGES.Where(i => i.ITEMID == item.ID).ToDictionary(i => i.ID, i => i.IMAGENAME)",  You are asking the framework to turn the "ToDictionary" method into SQL. It doesn't know how to do it. That's why it breaks. It looks to me like your model property should either be of a different type (like IEnumerable<T>) or be loaded separately.

Comment: You should write the EF query to actually perform the database query that you want, then, after writing the EF query that you want, you can write a query to execute in your actual application code that does whatever you can't do in the database.

Comment: Yes, I get it. Thanks a lot. Like I said, I didn't quite understand what the exception what saying.. although it makes perfect sense when you say it. What I did was making a model with int and string properties so now Images is List<newModel> and works. I'm too new to be able to vote you up but thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a navigation property between MERCHANDISE_IMAGES and MERCHANDISE_ITEMS

Comment: MERCHANDISE_IMAGES.ITEMID is a foreign key to MERCHANDISE_ITEMS.ID

Answer (score 1):

Short version: EF can't convert ToDictionary to SQL.

In my experience, the best way to go is to simplify the Select to an anonymous type with all the stuff from the DBOs you'll need, call ToList (or something else to force the evaluation) and then do the ToDictionary and other massaging of the data.

The added benefit of this is by forcing it to evaluate, you'll avoid leaving the using your context is in and closing it, which will cause an error when you try and use the return.